# MariaDB Query SUM() OVER (PARTITION BY)

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I have created a query that counts rows differently based on certain criteria (Date, isSpecial, isFirst, hour).
This is the query:

```
WITH test AS 
(
    SELECT customer_id, performance.id, performance_id, 
           Name, Date as zDate, Date, isSpecial, isFirst, hour 
    FROM recording 
    INNER JOIN performance ON performance_id = performance.id
)

SELECT id, Date, Name, isSpecial, isFirst, hour,
    IF(NOT isSpecial AND NOT isFirst AND hour,
        (SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN NOT isFirst AND NOT isSpecial
                AND hour AND Date <= zDate
              THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 
         FROM recording 
         INNER JOIN performance ON recording.performance_id = performance.id 
         WHERE customer_id = 1
        ), 
        IF(isSpecial AND NOT isFirst AND hour,  
            (SELECT CONCAT('P',SUM(CASE WHEN NOT isFirst
                    AND isSpecial AND hour AND Date <= zDate
                  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)) 
             FROM recording 
             INNER JOIN performance ON recording.performance_id = performance.id 
             WHERE customer_id=1
            ),  
            IF(isFirst,'First','-')
        )
    ) AS myTest 
FROM test 
WHERE customer_id = 1 
ORDER BY Date
```

#### Results:

[image: This is the result]

The query gives me the desired result for one customer_id without me having to set variables.

I have now experimented for a long time with SUM() OVER (PARTITION BY customer_id), but this always leads to "Subquery returned more than one record".

```
...
(SELECT CONCAT('P', SUM(CASE WHEN NOT isErst AND isProbatorik
                        AND therapiestunde AND Datum <= zDatum 
                     THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
            OVER (PARTITION BY customer_id))
 FROM leistungserfassung 
 INNER JOIN leistung ON leistungserfassung.Leistung_id = leistung.id),
...
```

Is it possible to extend this summation to all customer_id's, so that for each customer_id it is always summed up again?

Comment: Don't use a correlated subquery for that.  Just use SUM(...) OVER (PARTITION BY customer_id ....) AS xxx in the outer select list.  You won't even need the CTE term, most likely.

Comment: It's tough to test without the `CREATE TABLE` statements.  Your SQL doesn't qualify _each_ column reference, so we don't know which table contains each column.

Comment: `SUM(CASE WHEN boolean_expression THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)` can be shortened to `SUM(boolean_expression)`

Comment: Please show the _desired_ results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just a guess without sufficient detail about your schema / tables:

Try this (using MySQL 8.0, MariaDB 10.6, 10.5, 10.4, etc):

Note: If you want a running SUM, just add an `ORDER BY Date` clause (or something similar) to the window specifications.  It's possible the explicit date logic can be removed, depending on your actual requirement.  It's tough to tell without a little data and expected result.

[The fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.6&fiddle=f7ad06f30968e7bd3646a1590c4dce2d)

```sql
WITH test AS (
        SELECT customer_id, performance.id, performance_id
             , Name, Date as zDate, Date, isSpecial, isFirst, hour
          FROM recording
          JOIN performance
            ON performance_id = performance.id
     )
SELECT id, Date, Name, isSpecial, isFirst, hour
     , CASE WHEN NOT isSpecial AND NOT isFirst AND hour
            THEN SUM(CASE WHEN NOT isFirst AND NOT isSpecial AND hour AND Date <= zDate THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) OVER w
            WHEN isSpecial AND NOT isFirst AND hour
            THEN CONCAT('P', SUM(CASE WHEN NOT isFirst AND isSpecial AND hour AND Date <= zDate THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) OVER w)
            WHEN isFirst
            THEN 'First'
            ELSE '-'
        END AS myTest
  FROM test
WINDOW w AS (PARTITION BY customer_id)
 ORDER BY customer_id, Date
;
```

add running `SUM` (by `Date`) behavior to the window function and remove the explicit `Date <= zDate` logic:

```sql
WITH test AS (
        SELECT customer_id, performance.id, performance_id
             , Name, Date, isSpecial, isFirst, hour
          FROM recording
          JOIN performance
            ON performance_id = performance.id
     )
SELECT id, Date, Name, isSpecial, isFirst, hour
     , CASE WHEN NOT isSpecial AND NOT isFirst AND hour
            THEN SUM(CASE WHEN NOT isFirst AND NOT isSpecial AND hour THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) OVER w
            WHEN isSpecial AND NOT isFirst AND hour
            THEN CONCAT('P', SUM(CASE WHEN NOT isFirst AND isSpecial AND hour THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) OVER w)
            WHEN isFirst
            THEN 'First'
            ELSE '-'
        END AS myTest
  FROM test
WINDOW w AS (PARTITION BY customer_id ORDER BY Date)
 ORDER BY customer_id, Date
;
```

The result (with no data):

| id | Date | Name | isSpecial | isFirst | hour | myTest |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |

The setup (I'm sure these tables are not correct. The question did not include this detail):

```sql
CREATE TABLE recording   ( id int, performance_id int, customer_id int );

CREATE TABLE performance (
   id int, Name VARCHAR(20), Date date
 , isSpecial int, isFirst int, hour int
);
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This is working perfectly for me! Happy new year!